# Tricks for porting a large software project to tup build system

Tags: build-system, tup

What is the best way to port a software project with thousands of .cpp files and associated headers in a fairly well structured source tree to the tup build system?

If the tree looks like:

```
colors/                                                                            
 primaries/
  red.cpp 
  green.cpp
  blue.cpp
 fruity/
  orange.cpp
  grape.cpp
 grayscale/
  white.cpp
  gray.cpp
  black.cpp
some/annoying/nesting/animals/
    horse.cpp
    bear.cpp
```

for tens of categories with tens of target files in each, it really seems like a rather inelegant solution to write one-time use shell scripts to dump out Tupfiles in each directory, even if they are ~mostly similar thanks to sharing a Tuprules.tup.  What is the right, "best practice", hopefully portable way to do build projects like this with tup?

Comment: I realize that build systems with imperative config files, i.e. scons and CMake excel at this sort of task, but I'm pretty much sold on tup due to it's many virtues.

Answer (score 2):

With the recent addition of (still not well documented) LUA parser you can avoid having one Tupfile per directory. Take a look here http://gittup.org/tup/lua_parser.html read about Tupdefault.lua

Additionally - with recent change that allows output files in DIFFERENT folder you can simlify that even more. You can compile the files "somewhere", adding them to a global group(s), and then - when you need it, link/archive them all.

Simple Tuprules.tup:

```
TOP = $(TUP_CWD)
!cc = |> gcc $(CFLAGS) -c %f -o %o |> %B.o $(TOP)/<objects>
```

Simple Tupfile just for compilation (generic one, without modification to flags or sth):

```
include_rules

: foreach *.c |> !cc |>
```

Simple Tupfile for compilation and final linking (notes as above):

```
include_rules

: foreach *.c |> !cc |>
: $(TOP)/<objects> |> gcc %<objects> -o %o |> application.exe
```

Unfortunately I don't (yet) know how to use this particular feature (global groups) with LUA parser. I even asked about that on tup-users mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

From the tup manpage, tup supports running an external shell script:

```
      run ./script args
          Runs an external script with the given arguments to generate
          :-rules. This is an advanced feature that can be used when the
          standard Tupfile syntax is too simplistic for a complex program.
          The script is expected to write the :-rules to stdout. No other
          Tupfile commands are allowed - for example, the script cannot
          create $-variables or !-macros, but it can output :-rules that use
          those features. As a simple example, consider if a command must be
          executed 5 times, but there are no input files to use tup's
          foreach keyword. An external script called 'build.sh' could be
          written as follows:
```

You could trigger a script that generates he necessary tup rules, but I assume this is not portable, since you're relying on the shell.